# Como recorrer las imagenes que se guardan en una gallery desde wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

> las imagenes estan almacenadas en el post, puedo obtenerlas
> con la función `<?php echo the_post_thumbnail('medium', array()); ?>` 
> y cuando hago el llamado de la función 
> se muestran todas, quiero saber si con otra función como con `<?php echo the_post_thumbnail() ?>`
> hay posibilidad de mostrarlas agregando html y css personalizado

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de ingresar la función `the_post_thumbnail` en una variable usando un get, de esta forma $my_var = get_the_post_thumbnail('medium', array());

Luego realiza un var_dump de la variable $my_var `var_dump( $my_var );` posiblemente te regrese un array con los datos que requieres, luego solo necesitas recorrer ese array con un foreach para sacar cada elemento y lo concatenas con tu propio html.

Sin embargo, wordpress tiene una funcion especifica para traer las urls de las imagenes destacadas en caso de que solo desees la url para ingresarla en tu propio html, usando la función `<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>` la muestras como imagen así `<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">`

**Actualización**

La forma correcta de obtener los tamaños de las imágenes de un single seria mediante la función `wp_get_attachment_image_src` pasando como argumento el id y el tamaño y luego hacer echo de la respuesta, esto mediante un foreach o bien directamente al primer elemento

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); 

<img src="<?php echo $image['0'] ?>">
```

o mediante la funcion `the_post_thumbnail_url`

```
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'thumbnail' ); ?>">
```

Comment: $my-var no es una sintaxis para una variable, sin embargo se puede hacer var_dump(), y esta retorna un valor null, puedes tomar un capture y mostrar cuales son los datos que te muestra a ti cuando haces var_dump() a get_the_post_thumbnail() ?

Comment: Es correcto, el - no es aceptado para una variable en php, hice mi corrección, si estas usando solo get_the_post_thumbnail(); no retornara la información, deberás hacerlo de otra manera, revisa la actualización de la respuesta.